# What is the equivalent of @ManagedBean(eager=true) in CDI

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, cdi, managed-bean, eager-loading

As we all know that it is recommended to use annotations from `javax.enterprise.context` instead of `javax.faces.bean` as they are getting deprecated.

And we all found ManagedBeans with `eager="true"` annotated with `@ApplicationScoped`  from `javax.faces.bean` and having a `@PostConstruct` method are very useful to do web application initialization e.g: read properties from file system, initialize database connections, etc...

***Example :***

```
import javax.faces.bean.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

@ApplicationScoped
@ManagedBean(eager=true)
public class someBean{

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        //Do all needed application initialization.
    }
    ...
}
```

What I want to know is how can I get the same behavior if I used annotations from `javax.enterprise.context`.

***Note:***
`@Startup` annotation from `javax.ejb` will help to run that code but only at the moment of deployment of the webapp when the application server ***Starts***.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is not provided by CDI or JSF. You could homegrow your own with a custom CDI qualifier and a [`ServletContextListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) to hook on webapp start.

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface Eager {
    //
}
```

```
@WebListener
public class EagerListener implements ServletContextListener{

    private static final AnnotationLiteral<Eager> EAGER_ANNOTATION = new AnnotationLiteral<Eager>() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    };

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        CDI.current().select(EAGER_ANNOTATION).forEach(bean -> bean.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // NOOP.
    }

}
```

(note: `toString()` triggers lazy instantiation)

```
import com.example.Eager;
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;

@Eager
@ApplicationScoped
public class YourEagerApplicationScopedBean {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("Application scoped init!");
    }
}
```

As to existing libraries, only JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) offers [`@Eager`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/cdi/Eager) out the box.

```
import org.omnifaces.cdi.Eager;
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;

@Eager
@ApplicationScoped
public class YourEagerApplicationScopedBean {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("Application scoped init!");
    }
}
```

It's also [supported](http://omnifaces.org) on `@SessionScoped`, `@ViewScoped` and `@RequestScoped`.

Regardless of the approach, the only disadvantage is that `FacesContext` isn't available at the moment the bean is constructed. But that shouldn't be a big problem, with CDI you can simply directly `@Inject` artifacts of interest such as `ServletContext` or `HttpSession`.

Comment: One problem here, the qualifier `@Eager` should be added to injection point. Based on your answer, I posted an answer below that solves the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

CDI 1.1 also offers a standard way to observe scope lifecycle events, for instance:

```
public void processApplicationScopedInit(@Observes @Initialized(ApplicationScoped.class) ServletContext payload) {}
public void processApplicationScopedDestroyed(@Observes @Destroyed(ApplicationScoped.class) ServletContext payload) {}
```

For more information: http://www.next-presso.com/2014/06/you-think-you-know-everything-about-cdi-events-think-again/

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, you could use EJB instead of CDI. Then you can have a `@Singleton` with `@Startup`

```java
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;

@Singleton
@Startup
public class SomeBean {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        //Do all needed application initialization.
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Why not use your proposed bean and inject the CDI beans that you need to be eagerly instatiated? Name the class EagerInstatiator.

Comment: That would be just briedging. `EagerInstatiator` could directly be the name of this EJB. ALthough if you need a more complex orchestration you could do that, and use this EJB to orchestrate the different Beans that take part on the initialization

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach I use:

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Any;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager;
import javax.enterprise.util.AnnotationLiteral;
import javax.inject.Inject;

@Startup
@Singleton
public class AppStartup
{
    @Inject
    private BeanManager beanManager;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init()
    {       
        // enforce initializing eager CDI beans
        var beans = beanManager.getBeans(Object.class, new AnnotationLiteral<Any>(){});
        for(var bean : beans)
        {
            if(bean.getBeanClass().getAnnotation(Eager.class) != null && bean.getBeanClass().getAnnotation(ApplicationScoped.class) != null)
            {
                var beanProxyInstance = beanManager.getReference(bean, bean.getBeanClass(), beanManager.createCreationalContext(bean));

                // invoking toString() on the proxy object will invoke the method annotated with @PostConstruct, if has not been invoked yet
                beanProxyInstance.toString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({TYPE})
public @interface Eager {}
```

```
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;

@Eager
@ApplicationScoped
public class SomeCdiBean {}
```

Now you can inject this CDI bean without any extra qualifiers:

```
@Inject
private SomeCdiBean someCdiBean;
```

Comment: And if one starts using ejb's there is a more simple solution, see one of the other answers